# Заполнить массив

Tags: php, массивы

Подскажите, как заполнить следующий массив:

```
while($ser_row = $adb->fetch_array($sql)) {
    $carnomer = $ser_row['serialnumber'];
    $datanoy = $ser_row['cf_672'];

if (!isset($all[$ser_row['serialnumber']]))
    $all[$ser_row['serialnumber']] = array();
    $all[$ser_row['serialnumber']]['summs'] += (int) $ser_row['allmkad'];
    $all[$ser_row['serialnumber']]['dayes'] = $ser_row['cf_672'];
```

Выводит:

```
[х885рв140] => Array ( 
    [summs] => 20 
    [peregruz] => 0 
    [adres] => 0 
    [toplivo] => 0 
    [prostoy] => 0 
    [rabota] => 10030 
    [dayes] => 2013-06-27 
)
```

Как сделать, чтобы ключ `[dayes]` заполнялся всеми записями из while относящимися к `[х885рв140]`

Comment: @machanics, Перефразируйте, пожалуйста, Ваш вопрос: исправьте грамматические ошибки, правильно расставьте запятые. Если ещё добавите побольше уточняющей информации, то Вы ускорите получение ответа.

Comment: @machanics, используйте, пожалуйста, кириллицу.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы получить нужные вам данные в виде массива, замените вот эту строчку:

```
$all[$ser_row['serialnumber']]['dayes'] = $ser_row['cf_672'];
```

На вот эту:

```
$all[$ser_row['serialnumber']]['dayes'][] = $ser_row['cf_672'];
```

Сейчас, насколько я понимаю, у вас сохраняется только последнее значение.

Как вывести все элементы из полученного массива:

```
$result = '<pre>';
foreach ($all[$ser_row['serialnumber']]['dayes'] as $day) {
   $result .= $day . PHP_EOL;
}
$result .= '</pre>';
echo $result;
```

Comment: А возможно реализовать в foreach вывод дерева?

Comment: Добавил в свой ответ способ вывода полученного массива.

Comment: foreach($all as $key => $ser) {
    if ($key == ''){
   } else {
   foreach ($ser['dayes'] as $day) {
    $resultss .= $day . PHP_EOL;
   }
   $lislauto .= "<tr>
     <td class=\"dvtCellLabel\">" .$key."</td>
     <td class=\"dvtCellLabel\">" .$ser[rabota]. "</td></tr><tr><td>". $resultss ."</td></tr>";     
    }
   }